# How can grep treat escaped newlines as real newlines?

Tags: grep, newline

I'm using grep to find a word in some directory:

```
grep -r my_word directory
```

In this directory there are files containing `my_word` with escaped newlines (`\n`) so the output from `grep` is similar to:

```
file_name.txt:first line\n second line my_word\n third line
```

How can I force `grep` to treat `\n` as new lines and show something like:

```
second line my_word
```

Answer (score 1):

You could pipe the result through sed to convert the newlines, then grep again:

```
grep -r my_word directory | sed 's/\\n/\n/g' | grep 'my_word'
```

Alternatively, if your grep supports Perl compatible regular expressions (such as GNU grep), you can use look-arounds:

```
$ grep -Po '.*^|\\n\K.*my_word.*?(?=\\n|$)' myfile
 second line my_word
```

This uses a variable-length look-behind, `.*^|\\n\K`, to greedily remove everything up to the last occurrence of `\n` before the line with your search term, and `.*?(?=\\n|$)` non-greedily matches the rest of the line until the next `\n` (or end of line).

If you don't want the filename in your result in case the match is in the first "subline", you can suppress the filenames with `grep -h`.